# BaseOn not working properly

Tags: wpf, mahapps.metro

I'm trying to inherit the Mahapp style of Datagrid, I've created a style for the rows of the Datagrid like this:

```
<UserControl.Resources>       
    <Style x:Key="DataGridRow">
        <Style.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="DataGridRow" BasedOn="{StaticResource MetroDataGridRow}">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Selected}" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightGray"></Setter>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </Style.Resources>
    </Style>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

Unfortunately when I apply this style on the Datagrid I get the default style of wpf and not mahapp, what am I doing wrong? thanks

```
 <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" CanUserAddRows="false" Style="{StaticResource DataGridRow}">
```

Comment: Does the Output Window say anything? Also, how do you apply this style to the DataGrid rows? Can you show us the xaml?

Comment: @MassimilianoKraus question updated and no, there is no error

Comment: I don't know Mahapp, therefore I ask: what's the `TargetType` value of the Style `MetroDataGridRow`?

Comment: Drop `x:Key="DataGridRow"` and use `TargetType = "DataGridRow"` instead

Comment: @o_O nope not working

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must set your custom style to the `RowStyle` property of the `DataGrid`, cause the `DataGrid` doesn't look for implicit row styles.

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="CustomRowStyle" BasedOn="{StaticResource MetroDataGridRow}" TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Selected}" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightGray" />
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

Usage:

```
<DataGrid RowStyle="{StaticResource CustomRowStyle}" />
```